# Filtering a file on a string

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk

I have a file which looks like this

```
a   0   gene1   56  0   6S32M12S    *
b   256 gene2   56  0   6S32M12S    *
c   256 gene3   55  0   6S27M17S    *
d   16  gene4   110 9   19S25M6S    *
e   272 gene5   141 9   23S21M6S    *
f   272 gene6   139 9   24S20M6S    *
g   0   gene7   38  1   6S44M   *
h   256 gene8   38  1   6S44M   *
I   256 gene9   38  1   6S44M   *
j   256 gene10  40  1   8S42M   *
```

The 6th column is the string I want to filter on. Basically if the string contains a match equal to or more than 16S(so let's say 16S,17S,18S,19S and more) than report those lines. How can I do that? The out put for the above example would be:

```
c   256 gene3   55  0   6S27M17S    *
d   16  gene4   110 9   19S25M6S    *
e   272 gene5   141 9   23S21M6S    *
f   272 gene6   139 9   24S20M6S    *
```

I just showed you a little snippet from a big file.

Comment: Does the second S count?

Comment: So now you have `*` around the text or is that a formatting error?

Comment: Thats a formatting error. Fixed it..

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -ane 'print if grep {$_ >= 16} ($F[5] =~ /(\d+)S/g)' file
```

outputs

```
c   256 gene3   55  0   6S27M17S    *
d   16  gene4   110 9   19S25M6S    *
e   272 gene5   141 9   23S21M6S    *
f   272 gene6   139 9   24S20M6S    *
```

That finds all the digits followed by "S" in the 6th field. If any are greater than or equal to 16, it prints the line.

---

Look for `-n` in [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

One cool way to see what perl is doing with a one-liner is to add the option `-MO=Deparse`

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -ane 'print if grep {$_ >= 16} ($F[5] =~ /(\d+)S/g)'
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    our(@F) = split(' ', $_, 0);
    print $_ if grep {$_ >= 16;} $F[5] =~ /(\d+)S/g;
}
-e syntax OK
```

see
http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html
http://perldoc.perl.org/O.html

I'll explain by expanding the one-liner into a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
my $filename = shift @ARGV;
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die $!;
while (defined($_ = <$fh>)) {
    my @F = split(' ', $_, 0);
    my @s_numbers = $F[5] =~ /(\d+)S/g;
    if (grep {$_ >= 16;} @s_numbers) {
        print $_;
    }
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: Hi glenn, This works perfectly. Can you explain what you did here. For some reason I can easily understand perl in the script form but not on command line. If you could explain the code , it would be really nice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the second `S` also matters:

```
awk '{
split ($6, nums, /S([0-9]+M)?/); 
for (i in nums) 
  if (nums[i] > 16) 
    { print; next }
}' test.txt
```

Comment: Hi muru,
The code isn't working. Also I changed the input file a bit since I encountered this thing now. Please have a look. Help!!!

Comment: @user3138373 try the second code.